# Duplicate Answer Created When Editing Original Answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, specific-question

Something really weird just happened [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319205/jquery-ajax-live-validation-timeout-question).

I answered the question and then clicked edit to add a few more details. Once I submitted the edit, a new answer was added instead of editing my original one. I deleted the original answer so only users with 10k+ rep can see it, but the bug is there.

Comment: Did you check your browser history wether you ever went to so/posts/number/edit?

Comment: There was a (actually two) similar ticket during the UserVoice era. I don't know how/if it was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

*Testing "back button" theory.*

If you see this post it is because I just posted an answer ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16672/duplicate-answer-created-when-editing-original-answer/16675#16675)) and hit the "back" button to edit it. This would create a second post (this one).

---

[original message]

Are you sure you did not hit the "back" button on your browser to get back to the editor?

That will cause a second answer to be posted as an apparent duplicate.

Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you did not hit the "back" button on your browser to get back to the editor?

That will cause a second answer to be posted as an apparent duplicate.

Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That is an interesting theory, but I am sure I didn't do that. I hope not, anyways. :P

Comment: I've done it.

Comment: I guess I did it. Otherwise it has happened to me.

Answer (score 1):

if the flow is this:

1. add an answer
2. realize you want to change your answer
3. **instead of clicking the edit menu item on your newly submitted answer, you press the back button in your browser**
4. "edit" your answer (note that you're not really editing, but adding *another* answer) and click submit

That would most certainly add a second answer, and it's also impossible for us to detect, as you are adding two different answers with the "edit".

Comment: I checked, and I didn't do this. It happened by clicking edit and it created the new answer. I would obviously expect clicking back to add a new answer, but it's not what I did.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've **never** seen such a bug in my past ~1500 answers. I've edited many of them, many times.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not sure what that is supposed to mean. I've got ~1000 answers and I have certainly edited them many times. I'm not saying it's a critical bug but the behavior I am describing happened.

Comment: @Paolo: I know; but are you 100% sure that you didn't do anything like the "back button theory" or similar stuff? If it was a reproducible bug, it should have happened to more people by now.

Comment: actually it's very easy to detect. Just put some hidden value in the <form> and bind it to the post when it's posted; when the form is submitted check if that value has already been bound to another post.