# Using your browser's back button may result in posting an answer twice

Tags: bug, answers, back-button

Under some circumstances, when posting an answer and using the browser's back button, hitting the 'Post Your Answer' button again results in the answer being posted twice. This happened to me [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391137/4751173) by accident; I thought I was *editing* my original answer. I was able to reproduce it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337708/295232):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEafIYCq8os

(note the orange banner which appears halfway, AFAICR it didn't appear when I first experienced the bug on Meta Stack Overflow)

This bug report looks similar: [I was posting an answer, but it ended up appearing twice under a different question - bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299616/295232) but it has [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) so I'm not sure.

I would expect the Answer form to have some kind of GUID which prevents a form from being submitted twice, or that hitting the back button would empty the form. Either way would be a good solution to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: This is one of those "so just don't do it" bugs. SE can't really and shouldn't fix mistakes done by the users, IMO.

Comment: Did you post identical answers? I'm sure they block those - I have done this (press back, try to submit answer) accidentally and was greeted with a message that it's too similar to an existing answer or something to that effect

Comment: It happens [to the best ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320521/158100)

Comment: Definitely a bug that needs fixing, not a “let’s blame the user” moment.

Answer (score 18):

#### Testing "back-button theory"

If you see this post, it is because I just posted an answer ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337726/98786)) and hit the "back" button to edit it. This sequence of activity will (theoretically) create a second post (this one).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Write an answer
2. Click `Post Your Answer`
3. Notice an omission or improvement and click the browser 'back' button to edit
4. (the previous answer appears in the text editor): edit your answer
5. Click `Post Your Answer`

You will see a second, new answer posted

---

#### Conclusion:

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) ***confirmed***

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16672/duplicate-answer-created-when-editing-original-answer) and similar reports were previously marked [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), but I've since recreated this effect (usually inadvertently) many times.

Answer (score 2):

Test post, please ignore. Testing back-button theory (revisited).

See the results in my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337727/98786